# Output Merged HTML with own <TR> ID's

Tags: html, windows, powershell

I have a script which get a tcp connections `Get-NetTCPConnection`.
The `$flam` variable can get last record for each object, and the `$rfrt` variable can get all output objects without the last one.
As I show the `$CntTableBodyr` variable is my mistake, I want to add `$flam` and `$rfrt` variable as **HTML table** with the following details :

Each `tr` of the `$flam` which has recognized by ***Id=111***, to the first row then the `$rfrt` which has recognized by ***Id=222*** to those rows which contain by the first above rows digitalis!

**Can't understand?** Here what I mean :

Screenshot :
[image]

**Explanation** :
For example, in my `$GetCon` variable which includes all tcp-connections [as you know]. my complete output count is `[7 Count]` as I show in above image, for example the `[OwningProcess for 1177]` has 3 count result, and so on, I want to get last object of 1177 as the first row with `id=111` then second and all connections about 1177 to bottom. Other connections are same as 1177 and `[LocalAddress]`.

**Example**:

```
$GetCon = Get-NetTCPConnection
$ss = $GetCon | select OwningProcess | Group-Object -Property OwningProcess | select Count, Name

$cccs = $ss | Select -ExpandProperty Name

$flam = ForEach ($oio in $cccs) {
$GetCon | Where-Object {$_.OwningProcess -eq $oio} | select -Last 1
}


$yyoiu = $GetCon | Group-Object -Property OwningProcess

for ($irt = 0; $irt -lt $yyoiu.Count; $irt++)
{ 

$rfrt = foreach($grpop in $yyoiu[0..$irt]){
$jrtgrpcnt = [int]($grpop.Group.Count - 1)
$grpop.Group | select -First (0+$jrtgrpcnt)

  }
}


$CntTableBodyr=""
#$frcntArrr = $flam | select -ExpandProperty OwningProcess #$frcntr.GetEnumerator() |%{$_}
ForEach ($Rowr in $flam) {
  $CntTableBodyr+="<tr id='111' style='background-color: lightblue;'><td>$($Rowr.OwningProcess)</td><td>$($Rowr.LocalAddress)</td></tr>
  <tr id='222' style='background-color: lightgray;'><td>$($rfrt.OwningProcess)</td><td>$($rfrt.LocalAddress)</td></tr>"
}

$html=@"
<table id='tblId'>
$CntTableBodyr
</table>
"@

ConvertTo-Html -Body $html | Out-File c:\out.html
Invoke-Item c:\out.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just taking the essential part (as I do not have access to the same resources):

```
$flam = ConvertFrom-CSV @"
OwningProcess,LocalAddress
1177,127.0.0.1
1177,192.168.1.2
1177,192.168.1.1
2211,192.168.1.1
2211,127.0.0.1
3122,192.168.1.1
3122,192.168.1.1
"@

$OwningProcesses = @()
$flam | ForEach {
    $id = If ($OwningProcesses -Contains $_.OwningProcess) {"222"} Else {$OwningProcesses += $_.OwningProcess; "111"}
    $_ | Add-Member -Force id $id
}
```

Result:

```
PS C:\> $flam

OwningProcess LocalAddress id
------------- ------------ --
1177          127.0.0.1    111
1177          192.168.1.2  222
1177          192.168.1.1  222
2211          192.168.1.1  111
2211          127.0.0.1    222
3122          192.168.1.1  111
3122          192.168.1.1  222
```

Including this in the HTML file:

```
$CntTableBodyr=""
#$frcntArrr = $flam | select -ExpandProperty OwningProcess #$frcntr.GetEnumerator() |%{$_}
$flam | {
  $CntTableBodyr+="<tr id='$($_.id)' style='background-color: lightblue;'><td>$($_.OwningProcess)</td><td>$($_.LocalAddress)</td></tr>"
}

$html=@"
<table id='tblId'>
$CntTableBodyr
</table>
"@

ConvertTo-Html -Body $html | Out-File c:\out.html
```

Comment: sir, I want to Add <tr id='111' and <tr id='222' in html file

Comment: Apparently you didn't create this code yourself other wise you would have known how to continue from there. Nevertheless, I have added this to the answer. Your up-vote will be appreciated if it works as expected.

Comment: sir it will give same result nothing change, please can you post totally code?